# Put extras for Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have one general class for showing dialogs in Android. How do I pass extras to this class, that extends `android.app.Dialog`?

For Activities I can use `getIntent().getIntExtra()` for example.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can pass through constructor?

Comment: you want to pass to dialog data for example int?

Comment: @Geralt yes. Actually I need to send it the dialog title as string.

Comment: But maybe you can override constructor and then pass what you need? For example create constructor with 2 fields (context, andYourDataObject). Call super (context) and then set your data to fields in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I pass extras to this class, that extends android.app.Dialog

At first i would like to say that you didn't provide more details about your current implementation so following thing i mention is that i assume you have some method that returns dialog (you mentioned that you are using one class that stores various dialogs).

So what about to pass data directly through method?

```
public static final Dialog getDialog(int id, String title) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Or you can use constructor to reach your goal:

```
public Dialog(Context context, String title, int data) {
   super(context);
   this.title = title;
   this.data = data;
}
```

Note that you can create whatever constructor with as many parameters as you want. Dialog class just requires calling one of super constructors:

```
super(Context context);
super(Context context, int theme);
super(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener listener);
```

So if you're calling one of them you are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would pass extras to a dialog.

1. Create a static method that will create the dialog and set the extra in the bundle.

   ```
   public static final String TAG = "ExampleDialog";

   private static final String BUNDLE_TITLE = "title"

   ...

   public static ExampleDialog newInstance(String title) {
       ExampleDialog dialog = new ExampleDialog();
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString(BUNDLE_TITLE, title);
       dialog.setArguments(bundle);
       return dialog;
   }
   ```
2. In the `onCreateDialog` method access the string in the bundle

   ```
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
       final String title = bundle.getString(BUNDLE_TITLE);
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Create the dialog

   ```
   ExampleDialog dialog = ExampleDialog.newInstance("Title of Dialog");
   dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), ExampleDialog.TAG);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use another constructor, for example :

```
public class MyClass extends Dialog
{
    private Integer data;

    public MyClass(Context context){super(c);}
    public MyClass(Context context, Integer value)
    {
        super(c); 
        data = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can use data from elsewhere in your class.